# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_add_music.upload error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I wrote a code to upload images of music and it works ,but when I try to edit  older posts (I hadn't add img field yet) It shows following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_add_music.upload
```

Models.py

```
class add_music(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=0,null=True)
    genre = models.TextField()
    duration = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3,decimal_places=2,null=True)
    upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to='images/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.title()+" by "+self.artist
```

views:

```
def edit_music_view(request,music_id):
my_object = add_music.objects.get(id=music_id)

if request.method != 'POST':
    form = add_music_form(instance=my_object)
else:
    form = add_music_form(instance=my_object,data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
context={'form':form,'my_object':my_object} 
return render(request,'pages/edit_music.html',context)
```

Template file:

```
{% extends 'pages/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>{{ my_object }}</p>

<form action="{% url 'pages:edit_music' my_object.id %}" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="yes">save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: it looks like it is having an issue with the 'upload' field. You may need to back fill empty values using some SQL if you've added that field.

Comment: whats sql and upload field was there since i started project

Comment: which line is being reported in your error? SQL would be a command you run to insert a date into all of the `upload` fields that don't have a date. Can you view your data to verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always change that field to:

```
upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

that should fix that problem.

PS you should not name classes with `snake_case`. It's bad habit.

Comment: i couldnt use timezone "pages.add_music.upload: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present." this error happened but but null worked ,how can i fix this error and can i ask if u explain why this error occurred i just want to know and avoid it next time, thank you for hlp

Comment: @Nicolas_Darksoul if you add new field to existing database it has to populate previously added objects. If the field has attribute `null` set to `False` (default behaviour), then you have to provide `default=` value. I forgot that `auto_add_now` does not accept default attribute, so in this case you needed add `null=True`.
If you create clean db and clean your migrations, you might do it without setting `null`. But don't try it, if you don't have experience with organising migrations.